# Best Practice: Spring boot application behind a proxy or direct?

Tags: java, spring-boot, security, load-balancing

I want to set up a webservice (spring boot) and a web-gui (spring boot + Vaadin) but currently I'm not sure, whats the best setup for my needs.

Thank you for your advice and suggestions

**Things I have in mind**

- Security
- Latency
- Loadbalancing between multiple software instances (web-api is stateless; web-gui is stateful of course)

**Option #1**
Should I place the webservice behind a HTTP reverse proxy? I think its a good choice to split the application itself from the configuration of the transport layer (http/2, tls). So it could be easier to migrate to http/3 when its supported by the reverse proxy.
Whats about the latency, when the proxy speaks http/2 (or later http/3), but the service itself only http/1.1 ?

**Option #2**
Should I connect the service directly to the network, to reduce latency?

Comment: If you want to load balance and auto scale then there is no question - you must have a load balancer. Similarly if you deploy in any modern environment you’ll likely be deploying to Kubernetes - again, no question; you have to configure an ingress. So in the general case you will have a reverse proxy of some sort but without knowing about your deployment topology this question has no factual answer and is hence opinion based.

Comment: When I read Loadbalancer in your post, it also struck me that it requires a proxy.

Question answered. Thanks ;-)